# In what comics do the Gog Wars take place?

Tags: dc

I've seen people talk about "Gog Wars" where Superman meets an intelligent version of Doomsday that's been fighting an army of Gog clones for years. In what comics (specific issues) does this take place?

Comment: http://www.killermovies.com/forums/archive/index.php/t-384951-gog-wars.html

Answer (score 1):

Looks like at least part of what you're talking about happened in [Action Comics Vol. 1 #825](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Action_Comics_Vol_1_825):

> Dozens of Gogs, plucked from different points in time, attack the Man of Steel. Superman tries to fight them off, but the combined might of all of them forces him to the ground. When Gog is about to deliver his killing blow, Doomsday suddenly arrives and begins to toss Gogs around with little effort. As no one is going to kill Superman but Doomsday.

Apparently this and other related stories have been collected in the trade paperback [*Superman: In the Name of Gog*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/140120757X)